# USB SD card reader recognized with lsusb but no storage device shown with lsblk

Tags: mount, sd-card

I have a 2GB Micro SD card and a USB card reader. When I run `lsusb` I can see the card reader is recognized, but when I run `lsblk` I see no additional storage devices.

```
[lane@Lane-ArchSystem 19:38:08 ~]$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 041e:4069 Creative Technology, Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 046d:c00e Logitech, Inc. M-BJ58/M-BJ69 Optical Wheel Mouse
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0b38:0010 Gear Head 107-Key Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
[lane@Lane-ArchSystem 19:38:13 ~]$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0  1.4T  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0  1.4T  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0    1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0 1023M  0 part 
sr0     11:0    1 1024M  0 rom  
[lane@Lane-ArchSystem 19:38:17 ~]$
```

Not sure what the problem might be I've never run into anything like this before.

EDIT: Forgot to mention that I did have the SD card in the reader before I plugged it into the USB port.

Comment: Sorry I'm a little hectic at the moment, I just realized that I didn't have the card reader in when I copied the output from my terminal. Though the output wasn't any different from lsblk when I did have it plugged in.

Here is the output from it now

   [lane@Lane-ArchSystem 19:38:17 ~]$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 041e:4069 Creative Technology, Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 05e3:0723 Genesys Logic, Inc. GL827L SD/MMC/MS Flash Card Reader

Comment: Can you add that output to the question? Is rather difficult to read from a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I ran in the same trouble and lost hours to figure out why this happens.
My USB SD card reader was correctly listed with lsusb but no blk device was ever available when I put the card in.
It turns out that the problem was simply hardware. Any SD above 2Gb is an SDHC, and older readers are simply incompatible with those.
The only solution is to buy another reader, more recent, that supports SDHC (up to 64Gb), and be sure to install the exFAT packages: fuse-exfat and exfatprogs.
Be aware that the older exfat-utils is now replaced by the above mentioned exfatprogs and they are not compatible with each other.